# request node module not giving html

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, npm

I am using request nodejs module to get html for a website as below:

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://www.thenewschool.org/", function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("body>>>>>>>>>>");
    } else {
        console.log("error>>>>>>>>>"+error);
        console.log("response statusCode>>>>>>>>>"+response.statusCode);
        console.log("response body>>>>>>>>>"+response.body);
    }
})
```

and this gives me this output

> error>>>>>>>>>null
>
> response statusCode>>>>>>>>>403
>
> response body>>>>>>>>>Sorry, this request has been blocked due to an
>   invalid user agent.

This is passing for most of the cases, but fails in this case, can someone  help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you are receiving an HTTP 403 error code : Access Is Forbidden.

this probably means that your request has been "profiled" as "we don't want you here" :

- this can be because your IP has been flagged
- or because your are missing a header that would make your request look like the one of a real browser. Most probably the user-agent header given the body of the answer

Answer (score 11):

You just have to pass the `user-agent` in the headers (because the URL requires it), like:

```
var options = {
  headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}
}

request("http://www.thenewschool.org/", options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("body>>>>>>>>>>" + body);
  } else {
    console.log("error>>>>>>>>>"+error);
    console.log("response statusCode>>>>>>>>>"+response.statusCode);
    console.log("response body>>>>>>>>>"+response.body);
  }
})
```

Comment: I have one new issue now, This module is not giving me right html for redirecting website, I am passing this   var options = {
        url: "http://www.amwasia.com",
        headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'},
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        followAllRedirects: true
    }; and is not giving me right html (body for this case), this url is redirecting to http://www.amwmotors.com/

Comment: If you're using the same code as above, you're receiving a `200` status code, which isn't a redirect. If you tested the url `www.amwasia.com` through the browser and was redirected, maybe it was done through the html `<meta>` tag. But, through the `request` module, it seems that you're getting a `200`, and not a `3xx`.

Comment: I am getting a 503 statusCode when adding the user-agent but a 403 without it.